# Possible to selectively blacken out individual monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, sleep, hdmi, screensaver

Is there a way to somehow selectively "blank" or blacken an individual monitor while it's on through some type of "topical" solution?

I have three monitors, and sometimes I want to view solely on one monitor with the other two monitors blank. As the displays are DisplayPort and HDMI, turning them off or even putting them into power-save sleep causes Windows to jumble the windows and desktops as it reconfigures the system display.

I understand that this is a core function of Windows, and that it's apparently not possible to selectively "sleep" individual monitors without the display subsystem reconfiguring.

Is there perhaps a way to do this with some type of screen blanking program? Perhaps being able to somehow run "blank" screensavers on individual monitors. I've also wondered about a "Darkroom" type program that (topically) blanks out the the rest of the displays, besides the forefront program you're working in.

Comment: Just don't look at them? Make the background solid black and minimize windows?

Comment: How about a black Powerpoint/Impress presentation? You can select on which monitor the presentation should run.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a similar solution brought me here.

Then I had an idea which served the purpose.

Though the thread is old, I am posting in case someone else is looking for similar.

There are certain screensavers that allow options for you to customize which monitors they show on. Pretty straightforward, advanced settings of the screensaver.

From there one would select options to customize for desired results.

Comment: Your answer is a little terse, if you make reference to a resource such as "certain screen savers" providing a link to an example of such a screensaver would be very helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Right click on desktop and then on display options (assuming that the operating system is Windows 7). You will see the options for your display devices. Specifically, which device should be active and what to display on which device.

Comment: I notice you've used a lot of txtspk and have numerous spelling mistakes in your answer. Using spellcheck (standard on many browsers!) and using slightly more standard english might have people looking more favourably on your answers and could lead to more upvotes.